# Kubernetes - How to aggregate application logs

Tags: kubernetes

I have a microservice deployed in a Tomcat container/pod. There are four different files generated in the container - access.log, tomcat.log, catalina.out and application.log (log4j output). What is the best approach to send these logs to Elasticsearch (or similar platform).

I read through the information on this [page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) Logging Architecture - Kubernetes 5. Is “Sidecar container with a logging agent” the best option for my use case?

Is it possible to fetch pod labels (e.g.: version) and add it to each line? If it is doable, use a logging agent like fluentd? (I just want to know the direction I should take).

Comment: The downside of the sidecart solutions is that the HPA is not happy with that (it calculates use over all containers in the pod, thus leading to unhandy scaling scenarios). Best way imo is to send the data straight to ES by your app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the best option for your use case is to have to have one `tail -f` sidecar per log file and then install either a `fluentd` or a `fluent-bit` daemonset that will handle shipping and enriching the log events.

The [fluentd elasticsearch](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch) cluster addon is available at that link.  It will install a fluentd daemonset and a minimal ES cluster.  The ES cluster is not production ready so please see the README for details on what must be changed.

Comment: I was thinking one sidecar (say "log-forwarder") per pod.  This container will have the fluentd or fluent-bit agent that processes all the four files and forwards to ES. Is having one sidecar with tail -f logfile better than the approach I'm considering?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to fetch pod labels (e.g.: version) and add it to each
>   line?

You can mount information from Pod metadata description to its file system, after that you can configure your agent to use this data. Here is an example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: volume-test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container-test
    image: busybox
    volumeMounts:
    - name: all-in-one
      mountPath: "/projected-volume"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: all-in-one
    projected:
      sources:
      - secret:
          name: mysecret
          items:
            - key: username
              path: my-group/my-username
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
            - path: "labels"
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.labels
            - path: "cpu_limit"
              resourceFieldRef:
                containerName: container-test
                resource: limits.cpu
      - configMap:
          name: myconfigmap
          items:
            - key: config
              path: my-group/my-config
```

> If it is doable, use a logging agent like fluentd?

Tomcat cannot send logs to Elasticsearch by itself, it needs an agent for that (e.g., Fluentd, Logstash). So, if you want to use **Exposing logs directly from the application** option, you need to build a Tomcat image with the agent in it. And it seems almost the same as **Using a sidecar container with the logging agent** option with a harder way to configure. **Exposing logs directly from the application** option is more related to applications developed by you.